# C# Class Library SQL Insert Into Select From

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a C# Class that will allow me to audit off data from a Live  table to an Audit table in SQL. Showing a complete history of changes made to the data.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_audit SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE ID = id
```

I've got that one working ok if the two tables columns match ok in my Class Library, what I really need to do is able to define columns:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_audit (cols) SELECT (vars) FROM tbl_data WHERE ID = id
```

Can someone explain how i can loop through each col passing through the required variable?  Is it even possible?  So it would look like:

```
INSERT INTO tlb_audit (col1, col2, col3) SELECT (col1, col2, col3) FROM tbl_data WHERE ID = id
```

my code would look something like:

```
class.connection = myconnection.cs
class.currenttable = "tbl_data"
class.newtable = "tbl_audit"

class.col("sqlColumn1_in_tbl_audit")
class.col("sqlColumn1_in_tbl_data")

class.col("sqlColumn2_in_tbl_audit")
class.col("sqlColumn2_in_tbl_data")

etc

class.commit
```

Comment: You'd have to execute a SQL command that gets the table structure, loop through the columns, and build your SQL statement.  How often to you expect the structure to change, though?

Comment: You have mysql and sql-server tagged, which is it?

Comment: Sorry ticked mysql by accident, its SQL Server.  Table structures won't change.

Comment: Are you  using a ORM framework of any sort or doing raw sql calls?

Comment: Why not implement in the database with Change Data Capture?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx

Comment: saying audit is maybe misleading, what i mean by audit is a table that just has the data as is it was before a SQL update.  The issue is the "audit" table will have extra fields, i.e. dateUpdated, updatedBy.

Comment: You should consider making this a Trigger on the table if you want to ensure you are capturing changes to the row data. That way other calls to update the data aren't going to skip capturing the changes.

Comment: If I could make a suggestion, investigate various database frameworks to simplify your life and make your applications more robust. I've seen far too many applications where programmers misuse sql commands, causing either performance or security issues or both. Many of those frameworks will provide mechanisms to create robust audit logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like this to get the table column names:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName'
```

Once you get back the result you can loop through the names to build your INSERT query. I'm not sure how this gives you auditing on the table though. I think you might be better off building that functionality using the DBMS, maybe using Triggers

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to email notifications for audited tables in one of our applications. It reads the entity state from EntityFramework's data context and formats the changes as a formatted json string.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{

    var auditChanges = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(t => t.State != EntityState.Unchanged && t.Entity.GetType().IsDefined(typeof(AuditAttribute),true))
            .Select(t =>
            {
                var entityType = t.Entity.GetType();
                if (entityType.BaseType != null && entityType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
                {
                    entityType = entityType.BaseType;
                }
                return new
                {
                    entityType.Name,
                    State = t.State.ToString(),
                    Changes = t.State == EntityState.Deleted ? null : t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames
                        .Where(pn => t.State == EntityState.Added || t.CurrentValues[pn] == null && t.OriginalValues[pn] != null || t.CurrentValues[pn] != null && !(t.CurrentValues[pn].Equals(t.OriginalValues[pn])))
                        .ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn]),
                    Original = t.State == EntityState.Added ? null :
                        t.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn,
                            pn => t.OriginalValues[pn])
                };
            });

    if (auditChanges.Any())
    {
        var auditMessage = new StringBuilder(2048);

        var changes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditChanges, Formatting.Indented);

        auditMessage.AppendFormat("Timestamp: {0}\r\nUser: {1}\r\nIP Address: {2}\r\n====================\r\n{3}\r\n",
            DateTime.Now, HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.User == null ? "" : HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
        Controllers.BaseController.GetIpAddress(HttpContext.Current),changes);

    NotificationManager.SendNotifications(NotificationType.Audit, this, GetDataSession(),null,auditMessage.ToString());
    }
    retval = base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I tag classes to be audited with this audit attribute:

```
public class AuditAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Like so:

```
[Audit]
public partial class Agency { }
```

If not using a framework, you'll need a way of identifying before and after snapshots of your table rows in order to build something similar. You could also store your audit log into the database or using a syslog style logging api.

```
Sample Audit Table:
Timestamp Date,
EntityName varchar2(50),
Changes varchar2(MAX)?
```

Here is a sample email that we get when someone changes a tracked table:

```
The following database changes were made to tracked objects:

Timestamp: 11/13/2015 2:02:34 PM
User: 
IP Address: 173.165.34.65
====================
[
 {
   "Name": "CarrierSetting",
   "State": "Modified",
   "Changes": {
     "DirectBill": true
   },
   "Original": {
     "Id": 531,
     "CarrierCode": "MEXIC",
     "AllowQuote": true,
     "AllowBOL": true,
     "DirectBill": false,
     "RequireDocusign": false,
   }
 }
]
```

The nice thing about this is that you could theoretically reconstruct the database at the time of the change by deserializing the Json strings.